# reliable local messaging in Tcl on Unix-like systems

Tags: linux, tcl

After some research, I have found that on Linux, Tcl doesn't support Unix domain sockets at all.

In the absence of the Unix datagram sockets, what is the native(*) alternative for the reliable local message-based many-to-one communications in Tcl for the Unix-like systems? A limitation of text-only communication would be acceptable.

UDP is unreliable even if used locally. TCP is not message-based, and Tcl doesn't offer `TCP_NODELAY` option. Pipes are only one-to-one. FIFOs have poor async semantics and are (similarly to pipes) only one-to-one. SysV message queues lack `poll()` support but anyway are also not supported by the Tcl. I went through all the usual alternatives, but failed to find what fulfills the role of the Unix sockets in the Tcl.

(*) I have found the `ceptcl`, an external module, but it is neither a part of the Tcl nor is bundled with any Linux distro. As such it is not an acceptable option.

Comment: As Tcl only includes the portable things in the core language, the Unix datagram sockets are in an extension by design. So the native solution is to use a platform specific extension to get the platform specific native stuff you like to have.

Comment: @schlenk I've been meaning to do unix-domain sockets sometime — they'd fit nicely with `socket` — but it's not a high priority issue for me by comparison with other things.

Comment: I'd personally use TCP. It may not have TCP_NODELAY but you can still flush it. I've managed to get real-time response (as measured by human eyes) by just using plain-old sockets and liberal sprinkling of flush. On most modern unixen, the loopback device is quite fast.

Comment: @slebetman, the bigger problem with the TCP for me is that one has to have a persistent connection, or establish connection every time it is needed. Even locally, TCP still has timeouts even during the connection establishment. Local messaging doesn't have these problems: stateless send with immediate result indicating either the message was sent, or not.

Comment: Yeah, but that's still the best choice IMHO. Especially since you want a one-to-many architecture. You can of course get TCP to behave as a datagram-based protocol with stateless semantics: HTTP.

Comment: @slebetman, you mean that there is already a built-in web server with support for REST/similar in Tcl?

Comment: Have you looked at [threads](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.htm#M16) and broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

As stated before in this thread, unix_sockets cannot be part of the core package because of portability issues.

An implementation of Unix sockets as extensions here: https://github.com/cyanogilvie/unix_sockets

It works on Linux. Compilation tested successfully on Debian 10.